# How to create a for loop to tune lambda and alpha for glmm elastic net?

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am using the MMS package in R to conduct an elastic net regression on a GLMM. What I want to do is tune the lambda (or mu which is what it is called in the package) and alpha values. I want to select the best combination of alpha and lambda.

Currently I have created a for loop that loops through alpha values from 0.1 to 0.9 and I am trying to do the same with alpha but it doesn't work. What I want is for each alpha (say 0.1) each lambda value in the sequence is used. For example, for alpha = 0.1 I want lambda = seq(10, by= -1) to be tried, and I want this for each alpha value.

```
mu <- seq(10, by = -1)

for (i in 1:9) {
  for (j in mu) {
    fit.name <- paste0("alpha ", i/10)
    list.of.fits[[fit.name]] <- lassop(X, Y, Z, grp = g, alpha = i/10, mu = j)
  }
}
```

This output for list.of.fits is a list of fits using different alpha values but the mu (lambda) is 1 when I want it to iterate 1 to 10 for each alpha value.

```
X = matrix of fixed effects, first column is intercept of 1
Y = vector of response variable
Z = 1 random effect
grp = group variable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution that might be faster.

```
mu <- seq(10)
alpha <- 1:9/10
df.of.params <- data.frame(expand.grid(mu, alpha))
names(df.of.params) <- c('mu', 'alpha')
list.of.params <- split(df.of.params, seq(nrow(df.of.params)))

list.of.fits <- mclapply(list.of.params, function(params) {
    lassop(X, Y, Z, grp = g, alpha = params$alpha, mu = params$mu)
})
```

If you want to parallelize just change `mclapply` to a regular `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

```
list.of.fits <- list()


for (i in 1:9) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    alpha.name <- paste0("alpha ", i/10)
    mu.name <- paste0("mu ", j)
    list.of.fits[[alpha.name]][[mu.name]] <- lassop(X, Y, Z, grp = g, alpha = i/10, mu = j)
  }
}
list.of.fits
```